# Flash Builder 4.5.1 for PHP warning statements

Tags: php, class, ide, flash-builder, suppress-warnings

In my own PHP classes I use include statements but it "appears" the Flash Builder IDE isn't able to "see" the include path because it's convinced that the class doesn't exist "Warning (orange underline) Class SQLConnectdb cannot be found" and a warning that says "assignment in a condition" even though it clearly does work as a PHP page. Ideally I'd like to be able to tell Flash Builder to either STFU or nominate "where" I know it exists. Let me show you:

```
myservice.php
<?php
    include_once("require.php");
    class MyService{
       public function getService(){
          $db = new SQLConnectdb(); //get Class cannot be found warning
          $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
          while($Mytable = $db->getnextrow()){ //get assignment in a condition warning
          }
       }
    }
?>
```

then in require.php

```
require.php
<?php
    include("apache2/htdocs/master.include.php");
?>
```

then in master-include.php

```
<?php
   define("access",1);
   function autoload_classes($class_name) {     
        include 'apache2/htdocs/classes/' . $class_name . '.class.php';
   }
   spl_autoload_register('autoload_classes');
   if (file_exists("./conf.inc.php")) include_once("./conf.inc.php");

?>
```

then in ./conf.inc.php

```
<?php
  if(!defined("access")) die("you cannot access this file directly");

  define("conf_db_host","somehost");
  define("conf_db_user","someuser");
  //SQL connection details, etc etc
?>
```

My question is, how can I stop flash builder from emitting warnings? It's not stopping me work but I HATE having false warnings, if they are wrong it upsets me.

Comment: Hate to say it but you wasted your money on unnecessary proprietary software.

Comment: ? flash builder makes mobile apps for iPhone, iPad, Android and Blackberry ?

Comment: with PHP? wow, that is new to me.

Comment: with PHP on the server and flash on the client? of course yes

Comment: you can disable both these warnings by going into Preferences, PHP (Right hand side twister) "Semantic Analysis Properties" (right hand side sub menu) then after it loads onto the left hand side expand the "Potential Programmer Problems" then chose to "Ignore" Assignment in condition" and "Undefined Class or interface"

Comment: does it in make a cup of tea as well? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can disable both these warnings by going into

```
 Preferences, 
 PHP (Right hand side twister) 
 "Semantic Analysis Properties" (right hand side sub menu) 
 then after it loads onto the left hand side expand 
 the "Potential Programmer Problems" 
 then chose to "Ignore" Assignment in condition" and "Undefined Class or interface
```